# Get waveform data from audio file using FFMPEG

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ffmpeg, asp.net-core

I am writing an application that needs to get the raw waveform data of an audio file so I can render it in an application (C#/.NET). I am using ffmpeg to offload this task but it looks like ffmpeg can only [output the waveform data as a png or as a stream to gnuplot](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform).

I have looked at other libraries to do this (NAudio/CSCore) however they require windows/microsoft media foundation and since this app is going to be deployed to azure as a web app I can not use them.

My strategy was to just read the waveform data from the png itself but this seems hacky and over the top. The ideal output would be a fix sampled series of peaks in an array where each value in the array is the peak value (ranging from 1-100 or something, like [this](https://api.clyp.it/jhpss1yx/soundwave) for example).

Comment: You can use the stream method to either pipe it to your app or save it to disk and read that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sabona budi,

Wrote about the manual way to get waveform but then to show you an example, I found [**`this code`**](http://blog.wudilabs.org/entry/c3d357ed/?lang=en-US)  which does what you want (or at the least, you can learn something from it).

1) **Use FFmpeg to get array of samples**

Try the example code shown here : http://blog.wudilabs.org/entry/c3d357ed/?lang=en-US

Experiment with it, try tweaking with suggestions from manual etc... In that shown code just change `string path` to point to your own file-path. Edit the `proc.StartInfo.Arguments` section to replace the last section to look like:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + path + "\" -vn -ac 1 -filter:a aresample=myNum -map 0:a -c:a pcm_s16le -f data -";
```

That `myNum` from the part `aresample=myNum` is calculated by :

```
44100 * total Seconds = X.
myNum = X / WaveForm Width.
```

Finally use the `ProcessBuffer` function with this logic :

```
static void ProcessBuffer(byte[] buffer, int length)
{
    float val; //amplitude value of a sample
    int index = 0; //position within sample bytes
    int slicePos = 0; //horizontal (X-axis) position for pixels of next slice


    while (index < length)
    {
        val = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
        index += sizeof(short);

        // use number in va to do something...
        // eg: Draw a line on canvas for part of waveform's pixels
        // eg: myBitmap.SetPixel(slicePos, val, Color.Green);

        slicePos++;
    }
}
```

If you want to do it manually [**without FFmpeg**](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+decode+mp3+to+%22pcm%22). You could try...

2) **Decode audio to PCM**
You could just load the audio file (mp3) into your app and first decode that to PCM (*ie:* raw digital audio). Then read just the PCM numbers to make the waveform. Don't read numbers directly from bytes of compression math like MP3.

These PCM data values (about audio **amplitudes**) go into a byte array. If your sound is 16-bit then you extract the PCM value by reading each sample as a `short` (*ie:* getting value of *two consecutive bytes* at once since `16 bits == 2 bytes length`).

Basically when you have 16-bit audio PCM inside a byte array, every two bytes represents an audio sample's **amplitude** value. This *value* becomes your **height** (loudness) at each slice. A slice is a 1-pixel vertical line from a *time* in the waveform.

Now **sample rate** means how many samples per-second. Usually 44100 samples (44.1 *khz*). You can see that using 44 thousand pixels to represent one second of sound is not feasible, so `divide` total seconds by required waveform `width`. Take the result & `multiply` by 2 (to cover two bytes) and that is how you much you jump-&-sample the amplitudes as you form the waveform. Do this in a `while` loop.

Comment: Incredible, thanks a lot! I actually managed to do the hacky solution but I will definitely give this one a try. Thanks for the pointers :). Not from Botswana but close enough (South Africa) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function described in [this tutorial](https://rodic.fr/blog/libavcodec-tutorial-decode-virtually-any-audio-file/) to get the raw data decoded from an audio file as an array of `double` values.

Summarizing from the link:

The function `decode_audio_file` takes 4 parameters:

- path: the path of the file to decode
- sample_rate: the desired sample rate for the output data
- data: a pointer to a pointer to double precision values, where the extracted data will be stored
- size: a pointer to the length of the final extracted values array (number of samples)

It returns 0 upon success, and -1 in case of failure, assorted with error message written to the `stderr` stream.

The function code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
 
 
int decode_audio_file(const char* path, const int sample_rate, double** data, int* size) {
 
    // initialize all muxers, demuxers and protocols for libavformat
    // (does nothing if called twice during the course of one program execution)
    av_register_all();
 
    // get format from audio file
    AVFormatContext* format = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(&format, path, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'\n", path);
        return -1;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(format, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not retrieve stream info from file '%s'\n", path);
        return -1;
    }
 
    // Find the index of the first audio stream
    int stream_index =- 1;
    for (int i=0; i<format->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (stream_index == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not retrieve audio stream from file '%s'\n", path);
        return -1;
    }
    AVStream* stream = format->streams[stream_index];
 
    // find & open codec
    AVCodecContext* codec = stream->codec;
    if (avcodec_open2(codec, avcodec_find_decoder(codec->codec_id), NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u in file '%s'\n", stream_index, path);
        return -1;
    }
 
    // prepare resampler
    struct SwrContext* swr = swr_alloc();
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_channel_count",  codec->channels, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_channel_count", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_channel_layout",  codec->channel_layout, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_channel_layout", AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_sample_rate", codec->sample_rate, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_sample_rate", sample_rate, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr, "in_sample_fmt",  codec->sample_fmt, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL,  0);
    swr_init(swr);
    if (!swr_is_initialized(swr)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Resampler has not been properly initialized\n");
        return -1;
    }
 
    // prepare to read data
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating the frame\n");
        return -1;
    }
 
    // iterate through frames
    *data = NULL;
    *size = 0;
    while (av_read_frame(format, &packet) >= 0) {
        // decode one frame
        int gotFrame;
        if (avcodec_decode_audio4(codec, frame, &gotFrame, &packet) < 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (!gotFrame) {
            continue;
        }
        // resample frames
        double* buffer;
        av_samples_alloc((uint8_t**) &buffer, NULL, 1, frame->nb_samples, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL, 0);
        int frame_count = swr_convert(swr, (uint8_t**) &buffer, frame->nb_samples, (const uint8_t**) frame->data, frame->nb_samples);
        // append resampled frames to data
        *data = (double*) realloc(*data, (*size + frame->nb_samples) * sizeof(double));
        memcpy(*data + *size, buffer, frame_count * sizeof(double));
        *size += frame_count;
    }
 
    // clean up
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    swr_free(&swr);
    avcodec_close(codec);
    avformat_free_context(format);
 
    // success
    return 0;
 
}
```

> You will need the following flags to compile a program that uses : `-lavcodec-ffmpeg -lavformat-ffmpeg -lavutil -lswresample`
> Depending on your system and installation, it could also be: `-lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswresample`

and its usage is below:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 
    // check parameters
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please provide the path to an audio file as first command-line argument.\n");
        return -1;
    }
 
    // decode data
    int sample_rate = 44100;
    double* data;
    int size;
    if (decode_audio_file(argv[1], sample_rate, &data, &size) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
 
    // sum data
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
 
    // display result and exit cleanly
    printf("sum is %f", sum);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```